# dict.__getitem__ performance with strings

Tags: python, string, unicode, dictionary, python-3.x

I'm using a `dict` to store cached paths in a filesystem I've implemented. The keys in the `dict` are all strings. After some profiling I've demonstrated that lookups in the dictionary are a bottleneck. My understanding is that `dict` is highly optimized. Unfortunately the precision of cProfile does not include the inner workings of the dict lookup code.

Is there some reason that lookups for strings would be so slow in Python 3?
Is there something I can do to workaround or improve the performance?

Comment: The python dict is supposed to be hashed and constant time. Short of changing the data representation, I cant really think of anything. Can you tokenize the strings in some manner to reduce their length or turn them into pure numerics? Also locals are quicker than globals by about x2, is this in a function or global code?

Comment: @gecko, this is done in instancemethods

Comment: Dictionary lookups with string keys are a bit slower in Python 3 than in Python 2, but not enough to change a non-bottleneck into a bottleneck. So Python 3 here isn't the issue. You need to show some code.

Comment: He does say it's a file system, if he means 'part of an operating system' I don't think Python would be the lang of choice for that :-) It might just be too slow. But yea, some more info would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a necessity to evaluate the source code to understand what makes the difference. Recently i've tried to port Python2 code to Python3, come up with same poor lookup times, Python2 is ~30% faster than Python3. This is not actual code but a dummy class to figure out where the problem actually is. Sample code:

```
"""
python3
"""
from time import time
from random import randint

class Wooaah:

    def __init__(self):
        self.length=100000
        self.a=dict()
        self.b=dict()
        self.count=int()
        self.s=float()
        self.e=float()

    def dummy_data(self):
        for i in range(self.length):
            self.a[i]=time()
            self.b[i]=time()

    def setod(self):
        self.s=time()
        for i in self.a:
            if self.b.get(i):
                self.count+=1
        self.e=time()

a=Wooaah()
a.dummy_data()
a.setod()
print(a.count)
print(a.e-a.s)
```